# Last child of breadcrumb font set to bold in opencart 2.0

Tags: opencart

In opencart 2.0.x on category page last child of breadcrumb text font is need to set as a bold.

Any one please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I am trying this .breadcrumb > .a li+li+li { font-weight:bold;} . But it works only for third category of breadcrumb .I need last category even it 2nd or 3rd or 4th .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php $count = count($breadcrumbs);?>

    <?php $i=0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
      <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?>
        <?php if( $i == $count-1){ ?>

           <?php echo '<b>'.$breadcrumb['text'].'</b>'; ?>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>

        <?php } ?>      

      <?php $i++; ?> 
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

Go to your front end theme folder category tpl change the breadcrumb div portion with this this code